# Rails app object in console versus in scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the `app` object inside a Ruby script that loads the Rails environment but I have only problems...

Script looks like this:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

app = Rails.application

puts app.users_path(21)
```

I get

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<BacklinkHealth::Application:0x007fd6fac80d60> (NoMethodError)
```

If I include `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` then it's ok...

but the problem is that I also need to call `app.get` and I don't know how to enable that.

Why is this app object so different in a script than it is in Rails command line?

Answer (score 1):

I see that `app` is a method in console and it returns an instance of `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` while Rails.application is `BacklinkHealth::Application`. So the solution is:

```
app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
```